# branching off 240v mains before breakers

Tags: code-compliance, 240v, splicing

I want a 240v receptacle in the garage of my townhouse here in the USA. Originally I thought I needed to add a 240v circuit breaker to my panel, however the panel (and the box) looks dated and is full. I noticed the main 240v 60A breaker is located outside my unit in the utility closet, the power cable runs into the ground via large conduits. Assuming I have access to the main power line for my unit, can I branch off that (before the actual circuit breaker panel) to power a 240v receptacle? If so, what's the best method and will it meet code?

Comment: Quite possible you need to have an license electrician.  Usually only owners of of a single family home can do their own work.  Rentals or multi family homes/buildings need an electrician.   How many amps you want/need for the 240 receptacle?   Cannot just splice into a wire just anywhere, it will need a junction box at least.  Your best bet is to probably add a sub panel to your main panel and work off that.

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: "Looks dated" is a fairly unimportant judgment, and "full" can usually be easily rectified ... especially if it's dated because there may be unused or underused circuits and may be ways to combine circuits or install half-height breakers to gain back space.   Post a picture of the panel, and describe any major loads it feeds (eg central air, electric hot water, etc).  Click "Edit" to add to your question and you can paste or upload a photo then.

Comment: Since you do own title to the facility in most areas in the US it is illegal to modify anything electrical unless you are properly licensed. I would recommend talking to the landlord or HOA whichever is applicable.

Comment: 60 amps is not much.  Imagine almost everything that heats or cools is by gas/wood.

Comment: **OP we'll need to know whether your state has adoped NEC 2020**.   @crip659 my place is 30A... *and what's more, it's 120V*.  No joke. Worse we used to share the 30A with the neighbor next door who likes air conditioners!  And we were half a MWBC! Only found when the electrician rewired it to give us each our own breaker and neutral. *I didn't know about it for the first 15 years, **because we didn't have problems for 15 years** and would have never known if not for the Lost Neutral incident* . It's amazing how little power you need with all-gas appliances.

Answer (score 3):

> can I branch off that (before the actual circuit breaker panel) to power a 240v receptacle?

So the receptacle would have *no overcurrent protection AT ALL?* No, that would be unbelievably dangerous at every level.

Fortunately there's no need to do that, since you say a 60A breaker is there.  We can simply tap *your side* of the 60A breaker, which is protected by the breaker. We will need to come off it with wire rated for 60A, then come to a disconnect or subpanel in the garage, which has the correct breaker for your application.

Tapping 60A wire can be done with a 3-hole Polaris connector; a short pigtail from breaker to Polaris and then the other 2 holes go to your original main feeder and to the new one.

Wire sizes *get really weird*.  Because this is the entire service to a dwelling, you get a special favorable derate, so 48.8A wire will suffice.  #6 aluminum is an option actually, which is cheap (and safe by the way).

Whether you need to tap 3 wires (neutral) or only two (hot-hot) is a conversation we need to have about your application. If it's an electric car, congratulations! Let's talk about the wisdom of trying to avoid a receptacle, and ways to save money on wire so you're not paying through the nose for #6 copper.

Comment: Can't the wire from the tap to the garage be rated for less than 60A if there's a suitable main breaker or just one breaker at the garage end ?

Comment: @jay613 Breakers protect wires.  For instance a long run of #14, shorted at the far end, might sit there glowing cherry red and the breaker would not instant-trip as it should, and would be in thermal trip zone and far too slow to act.  You are entitled to the 310.15(B)(7) derate, and that lets you use #6Al.  You can't beat the cost of that!